# How to feed grayscale images into a pretrained neural network models?

Tags: tensorflow, grayscale, transfer-learning

Noob here . I have been working with grayscale images for mitosis classification  [Here's a sample image I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpvUg.jpg) . I have employed VGGnet for achieving this. I've some doubts about how my grayscale image should be fed into the neural network. I've read the documentation of VGGnet about being trained on colored images on Imagenet.

I read the images using cv2.imread() and by squeezing into an array. I found its shape to be (227,227,3). Shouldn't it be (227,227,1) when I'm handling with grayscale images ? Model accuracy was also found to be only 50% . I'm wondering if it's something wrong with the dataset itself or VGGnet isn't suitable for this purpose. Or should I use some other method to read these images to get grayscale images?

I have tried the solutions listed in similar questions . Am I reading the images in the right way?

I'm sharing my code here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Display Image data 
from PIL import Image
import cv2

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

mitotic_image = Image.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualmito1/trainactmito01.jpg')
nonmitotic_image=Image.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualnonmito1/trainactnonmito01.jpg')

 # subplotting image data
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,9))
 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
 img_plot = plt.imshow(nonmitotic_image, cmap = plt.cm.bone)
 ax1.set_title("Non-Mitotic Image")

 ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
 img_plot = plt.imshow(mitotic_image, cmap = plt.cm.bone)
 ax2.set_title("Mitotic Image")
 plt.show()

 import os
 yes = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualmito1")
 no = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualnonmito1")

 data = np.concatenate([yes, no])
 target_yes = np.full(len(yes), 1)
 target_no = np.full(len(no), 0)

 # Image Target

 data_target = np.concatenate([target_yes, target_no])

 # Generate Image Data

 img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualmito1/trainactmito01.jpg")
 mitosis = cv2.resize(img,(32,32))
 plt.imshow(mitosis)

 X_data = []
 yes = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualmito1")
 for file in yes:
     img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualmito1/" + file)
     # resizing image data to 32x32
     img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
     X_data.append(img) # This will store list of all image data in an array

 no = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualnonmito1")
 for file in no:
     img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical/actualnonmito1/" + file)
     # resizing image data to 32x32
     img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
     X_data.append(img)        # This will store list of all image data in an array

 X = np.squeeze(X_data)
 X.shape

 # Image Pixel Normalization

 X = X.astype('float32')
 X /= 255
 X.shape

 # Train & Test Data

 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, data_target, test_size = 0.1, 
 random_state = 3)

 x_train2, x_val, y_train2, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size = 0.15, 
 random_state = 3)

 # VGG16 - Transfer Learning

 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Flatten, ZeroPadding2D, 
 Dropout, BatchNormalization
 from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
 from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16

 def build_model():
    #use Imagenet = pre-trained models weights called knowledge transfer  
    # image_shape = 32x32x3
    vgg16_model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False, input_shape=(224,224,3))

    # Input Layer
    model = Sequential()
    # paadding = 'same' = ZeroPadding
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', input_shape = (224,224,3)))

    # add transfer learning model
    model.add(vgg16_model)

    # Average Pooling Layer
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    # Fully Connected Layer
    model.add(Dense(units = 512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    # Output Layer
    model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['Accuracy'])

 return model

 model = build_model()

 model.summary()

 from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
 filepath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/BestModelMRI3.hdf5"
 checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, 
 mode = 'min',verbose = 1)


 import datetime
 import keras
 import os

 logdir = os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/MRI_logs", 
 datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
 tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir)

 history = model.fit(x_train2, y_train2, epochs = 200, batch_size = 32, shuffle = True, 
  validation_data = (x_val, y_val), callbacks = [checkpoint, tensorboard_callback],verbose= 1)

model.load_weights("/content/drive/MyDrive/BestModelMRI3.hdf5")


model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

predictions = model.predict(x_test)

yhat = np.round(predictions)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report 
confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat)
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, yhat), annot = True, cmap = 'RdPu')

print(classification_report(y_test, yhat))
```

Answer (score 0):

VGG model was trained on RGB images. CV2 reads in images as BGR. so add code

```
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

to convert BGR to RGB. Also VGG requires the pixels to be in the range -1 to +1 so scale with

```
X=X/127.5 -1
```

Comment: So is it ok if I read the grayscale images using cv2.imread() as RGB images ?